# Bulk DjVu to PDF converter

Tags: windows, pdf, document-converter, djvu

Necessary:

1. Windows 11 64 bit
2. Free
3. Can easily start converting (e.g. through drag and drop, selecting folder) an unlimited number of DjVus to PDF

Ideal:

- No bloatware, spam, popups asking me to upgrade

Comment: Cross-stack duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/185523/how-to-convert-djvu-file-to-pdf-or-other-more-common-file-format

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: The first word **bulk** is key. That post is about converting just one DjVu (I've found many solutions for that). I want to convert 100s or 1000s of DjVus to PDF without doing them one at a time.

Comment: One of the answers to that Super User question recommends a command-line (or Mac Terminal) tool. While the program may or may not be able to do multiple files at once, you can always write a batch file/shell script to loop through a list of djvu files and convert each one to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Boxoft Free DJVU to PDF](http://www.boxoft.com/djvu-to-pdf/) should do what you want.

Comment: I already tried it before. It can't even be installed: "Sorry! The application can not run in 64-bit Windows."

Comment: It runs on Windows 7 which is also 64-bit.

Comment: Posibly you´ve used some old version. This here should be the actual one: https://down10.software/download-boxoft-free-djvu-to-pdf-freeware/

Comment: Nope still the same error for me: "Sorry! The application can not run in 64-bit Windows."

Comment: An alternative could be this trial version of some comercial software: https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/djvu_to_pdf.html

Comment: Also there is this one: https://www.flipbuilder.com/free-djvu-to-pdf/